Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'. Error resolving plugin [id:'com.facebook.react.settings'] > java.io.UncheckedIOException:
i created a new react native project. when i start the build, it failed as its Minimum supported Gradle version is 8.7
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Hermon\ProductApp\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.



Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.version-check'.
Minimum supported Gradle version is 8.7. Current version is 8.5. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\Hermon\ProductApp\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-8.7-all.zip

what should i do if the minimum requirement is  gradle 8.7, if i change the gradle version from 8.5 to 8.7 it shows me error like this
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Settings file 'C:\Users\Hermon\ProductApp\android\settings.gradle' line: 2
Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react.settings']


java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\Hermon\ProductApp\android.gradle\8.7\dependencies-accessors\569c8b261a8a714d7731d5f568e0e5c05babae10-fe987f09-7166-4a3a-8da6-d83b539a3463) to immutable location (C:\Users\Hermon\ProductApp\android.gradle\8.7\dependencies-accessors\569c8b261a8a714d7731d5f568e0e5c05babae10)
BUILD FAILED in 53s


> To resolve the issue simple run the following command:
npm run android

If the command does not work on the first attempt, try running it again. This approach successfully resolved the problem for me, and it should work in most cases. Be sure that your development environment is properly configured, and Android Studio is set up correctly with all necessary SDKs.
